# Remove anaconda environment prefix from ubuntu terminal command prompt

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

I installed ancaconda and installed two versions of pythons as

```
conda create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda
conda create -n python3 python=3.6 anaconda
```

Now when I do `source activate python3`, the environment python3 is prefixed in my terminal. 
Before my terminal was : `source activate python3`, Now anaconda prefix environment 'python3' is added `(python3) shyamkkhadka@algo22:~$`.How can I remove the prefix (python3) from my terminal prompt, in ubuntu ?

Comment: Well, having the `(python3)` is nice to have so that you know that you're not using the standard env.  But, if you want to change the prompt, take a look at something like https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, I found the answer myself. Anaconda has nice feature for this also:

```
conda config --set changeps1 false
```

It hides the prefix in your command prompt.